# Use of vor in this sentence

Tags: word-usage

On the blurb of the book "Der Schwarm" the first sentence reads as "*Vor Peru verschwindet ein Fischer.*"

I only know "*vor*" to mean "before", "in front of" or "prior", but in this sentence it seems to mean "from".

Can you explain this?

Comment: "vor" can relate to time OR location, befor relates only to time while "vor Peru" means "located in fromt of Peru"

Answer (score 19):

Peru has a coastline, a fisherman is often in the sea. And there he disappears - somewhere before/in front of/not far from the coastline of Peru in the deep sea waters

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense

Comment: *Wir lagen **vor** Madagaskar, und hatten die Pest an Bord …*

Answer (score 10):

In this context it means `offshore`, because it refers to: `vor (der Küste)`.